# Dynamic Angular table not sorting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having some difficulty sorting a dynamic Angular table.

If I hard-code the table headers, it works.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xgL15jnf/

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType =  'id';    sortReverse = !sortReverse">id
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'id' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'id' &&  sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType =  'name';    sortReverse = !sortReverse">name
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'name' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'name' &&  sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType =  'cost';    sortReverse = !sortReverse">cost
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'cost' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                <span   ng-show="sortType  == 'cost' &&  sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

But, if I build the headers dynamically, it does not.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m31d00sz/

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="column in cols">
            <a href="#" ng-click="sortType = '{{column}}';    sortReverse = !sortReverse">{{column}}
                <span ng-show="sortType   == '{{column}}' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType   == '{{column}}' &&  sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The Search/Filter works in both Fiddles.

I'm hoping I'm overlooking something simple, and would appreciate if someone could take a look and provide some guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use interpolation braces `{{column}}` inside `ngClick` directive. It should be:

```
ng-click="sortType = column; sortReverse = !sortReverse"
```

And there is one more problem. Since `ngRepeat` directive creates new child scopes per iteration when you click you actually modify local scope `sortReverse` and `sortType` properties. The simple fix is to make use of prototypical inheritance, in which case ngClick will use properties from upper scopes resolved by prototypical chain.

For this in controller define

```
$scope.sort = {
    type: 'id',
    reverse: false
};
```

and in template:

```
<td ng-repeat="column in cols"> 
    <a href="#" ng-click="sort.type = column; sort.reverse = !sort.reverse">
        {{column}}
        <span ng-show="sort.type == column && !sort.reverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></span>
        <span ng-show="sort.type == column && sort.reverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
    </a>

</td>
```

and

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows | orderBy:sort.type:sort.reverse | filter:searchData">
    <td ng-repeat="column in cols">{{row[column]}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/m31d00sz/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing the ng-click to "sortType = column" as advised above, but that didn't seem to work. I also tried changing the sortType on the ng-show directives as well.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the explanation, and the Fiddle.